# Maximum number of rows a select statement can fetch

Tags: sql, database, select

Is there any practical limit of number of rows a select statement can fetch from a database- any database?

Assume, I am running a query `SELECT * FROM TableName` and that table has more than 12,00,000 rows.

How many rows it can fetch? Is there a limit for this?

Comment: Only your memory is the limit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`12000000` is not at all a big number I have worked with **way** bigger result sets. As long as your memory can fit the result you should have no problems.

Comment: I am actually facing an issue of counts. My table has ID column with value within range of 1-5 and that field is mandatory. It cannot be a null. 
When i run a query with where clause with condition like 

Select count(*) from TableName1 where ID=1 

lets say... it gives me count as 100000.

Comment: I follow same thing with four different IDs and assume all of them gives me same number as first one (guess for an example). 
So, as per the above queries, total number of records in my table is 500000.
Now here is an interesting thing. When I run same query without where clause, it is not giving me 500000 records. So I was wondering if there is any practical limit on this. Or anything related to memory?

And Thanks for your input.

Comment: Hmm no if query finishes successfully and you get results than all results were fetched. Maybe something else is the problem?

Comment: well there is the problem.. actually I should get 500000 rows but it comes bit short and its coming as around 450000 ..... so totally confused with this. Here I am using only dummy numbers to give an idea. Actual number is around 12L.

Comment: @tbp_09 is it possible that a single record is returned by more than one of the above queries?

Comment: i guess yes but finding it out would be real tough because it always returns correct result when we run with where clause.

Comment: My point is that if a record can be matched by more than one of the select queries with where clause it is logical to have the sum of the numbers of results of the select queries with where clause being more than the results without where clause.

Comment: Have you tried selecting records where the number is > 5, just to check that there are not errant records in place?